# Electron Dialog filePath "\\" to "/"?

Tags: javascript, json, windows, electron, dialog

I open an dialog in electron to select an folder and I want to read out the file path.
But the result.filePaths gives me an filePath with **\\** what is not workible for me, to read later the files in the folder.

**Result now:**

> "P:\\Social Media\\Soundboard\\Sounds"

**Expected Result:**

> "P:/Social Media/Soundboard/Sounds"

Is it any way to convert it to "/"?

#### My code:

```
const dialog = require('electron').remote.dialog

dialog.showOpenDialog({
    properties: ['openDirectory', 'multiSelections']
}).then(result => { 

 //Get Selected Folders
 folderpath = result.filePaths
 console.log(folderpath)
});
```

Comment: What is the the problem you're facing with file paths containing `\\ `?

Comment: I want to read all soundfiles in the directory and with fs.readdir it dosen't read the file path and I thinking its because the formatting. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses `\` to separate nested resources instead of `/`. But it supports both. If you still want to convert `\\` to `/`. You can try the below method.

```
//Get Selected Folders
 folderpath = result.filePaths.replaceAll('\\', '/');
 console.log(folderpath);
```

Comment: I did it. Thanks, I learned something new in JS. The replaceAll coming also handy later ^^

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I develop electron apps to work on both unix and windows without any issues.

Instead of using the `path` module function, I extended the functionality by using the module below and call that instead. This will sanitize all paths and convert them to correct unix paths like '/var/path/file' or 'C:/path/file'.

Windows can actually work with unix paths for creating/reading/updating/moving files and folders.

```js
export default {
  extname (file) {
    return path.extname(file)
  },

  resolve () {
    return this.sanitizePath(Array.from(arguments).join('/').replace('//', '/'))
  },

  normalize () {
    const file = this.resolve(...arguments)
    return this.sanitizePath(path.normalize(file))
  },

  basename (file, ext = '') {
    return this.sanitizePath(path.basename(file, ext))
  },

  dirname (file) {
    return this.sanitizePath(path.dirname(file))
  },

  relative (from, to) {
    return this.sanitizePath(path.relative(path.resolve(from), path.resolve(to)))
  },

  sanitizePath (absPath) {
    // fix windows separator
    return absPath.replaceAll(path.sep, '/')
  }
}
```

The only time I needed windows specific paths was with `shell.moveItemToTrash(file)` and for that I had to us this client side function

```js
convertPathForWin (file, os = navigator.platform) {
    return (os.toLowerCase() === 'win32') ? file.replaceAll('/', '\\') : file
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I dosen't thinking about unix yet but maybe for later it becomes useful if I testing my app on Linux and MacOS. But for now Windows is first 

Thanks for the reply 

Comment: If you're using Electron it's a shame not to deploy your app for linux and mac too.

Comment: No, I want to bring it also for Linux and MacOS out. But for any plattform, I have to make some optimization and code changes. Because of issues with alot of Soundboard Apps,
I decided to create my own. Before realeasing, I build it for all plattforms, dont worry 

Im usally more in web frontend work so I decided Electron firstly, because the easy dev experience. But I have to learn a lot on this journey ^^